# Debugging linux kernel over firewire

Tags: firewire, kgdb

I spent several days to look how to setup kgdb over firewire.
Target system is Ubuntu 14.04 kernel 3.19 and host system is Ubuntu 15.10 kernel 4.2 .
I tried fireproxy utility (http://halobates.de/firewire/) recompiled on my host system but debugging was not functional. Does anybody know about some tutorial how to set up kgdb over firewire on ubuntu ? I found many articles how to set it over serial, but not one about kgdb+firewire with exception above which is probably obsolete.

Comment: Did you had DEBUG_INFO, PROVIDE_OHCI1394_DMA_INIT, FIREWIRE_OHCI_REMOTE_DMA target kernel config options set?